# value=(@string/app_name). add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:3:4-40:19 to override. Error in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-manifest, jitsi-meet

I got like below error while using jitsi_meet plugin. I add AndroidManifest.xml file also but i got error. I add my app name also.

```
C:\Users\ammu\AndroidStudioProjects\Clinic_app\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:4:9-35 Error:
    Attribute application@label value=(clinic_app) from AndroidManifest.xml:4:9-35
    is also present at [org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:3.3.0] AndroidManifest.xml:34:9-41 value=(@string/app_name).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:3:4-40:19 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@label value=(clinic_app) from AndroidManifest.xml:4:9-35
    is also present at [org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:3.3.0] AndroidManifest.xml:34:9-41 value=(@string/app_name).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:3:4-40:19 to override.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 56s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

This is my error

```
    package="com.example.clinic_app">
    
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"> 
    <application 
        tools:replace="label"  
        android:label="@string/clinic_app"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    </application>
  
</manifest>
```

this is my AndroidManifest.xml file

can you give solutions?
Is there anything to change?
application label or tool replace.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an error in your manifest file:

Change this:

```
    package="com.example.clinic_app">
    
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"> 
    <application 
        tools:replace="label"  
        android:label="@string/clinic_app"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    </application>
  
</manifest>
```

to this:

```
    package="com.example.clinic_app"
    
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"> 
    <application 
        tools:replace="label"  
        android:label="@string/clinic_app"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    </application>
  
</manifest>
```

Notice I removed a misplaced '>' at the end of the 'package=...' line.

Answer (score 0):

create app/src/main/res/values/string.xml strings.xml and put inside

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name" translatable="true"/>
</resources>
```